# How to display random generated ID into more than 1 textbox

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm randomly generating an ID. i'm able to display out the generated random ID into one textbox via this method.

```
protected void btnRandom_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Random slumpGenerator = new Random();
        int tal = slumpGenerator.Next(10000, 999999);
        tbpid.Text = tal.ToString();

    }
```

I'm trying to display this random generated ID into more than 1 textbox which i attempted like this

```
protected void btnRandom_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Random slumpGenerator = new Random();
        int tal = slumpGenerator.Next(10000, 999999);
        tbpid.Text = tal.ToString();
        tbPassword.Text = tal.ToString();
        tbconfirmpassword.Text = tal.ToString();
    }
```

However, it doesn't work. I tried changing to

```
protected void btnRandom_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Random slumpGenerator = new Random();
        int tal = slumpGenerator.Next(10000, 999999);
        tbpid.Text = tal.ToString();
        tbPassword.Text = tbpid.Text;
        tbconfirmpassword.Text = tbpid.Text;
    }
```

But this particular randomly generated ID did not appear in the password and confirmpassword textbox. It only appears in the pid's textbox. I would like this particular generated ID to appear on all the 3 textbox once i click the generate ID button

Appreciate any help given :)

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean?

Comment: textboxs display nothing ?

Comment: hehe sorry. Left out something very important. Added. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In ASP.NET you can't set the value of a textbox with textmode="Password" directly (for safety reasons).

Try this instead:

```
tbPassword.Attributes.Add("value", tal.ToString());
```

Answer (score 3):

I assume that the textboxes tbPassword and tbconfirmpassword have the property TextMode set to password. You then cannot set the value with the Text property. Try changing the TextMode to see if that is indeed the problem.

A workaround is:

```
tbPassword.Attributes.Add("value", tal.ToString());
tbconfirmpassword.Attributes.Add("value", tal.ToString());
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you do it in Javascript

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $(tbPassword).Value = $(tbpid).Value;
    $(tbconfirmpassword).Value = $(tbpid).Value 
});
```